# Facebook Graph API - Post comment with photo

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a PHP script like:

```php
$facebook = new Facebook( array( 'appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_SECRET ) );

$facebook->setDefaultAccessToken( ACCESS_TOKEN );

$post_comment = $facebook->api( $object_id . "/comments", "POST", array(
    'source' => $facebook->fileToUpload('http://healthhub.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Group-Slider.jpg'),
    'message' => "Comment with photo!"
  ) );
```

Then, I checked on Facebook, it just like [result of post comment][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l5yp.png , in while, I want it like that: [result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYA6o.png)

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What's your question here? Which of the Ids is Thread ID?

Comment: Have you reviewed the api reference documentation? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference

Comment: @jmoney I have edited my question above. Please, help me!